# data-anchor-target and skrollr menu

Tags: jquery, menu, skrollr

I'm having issues understanding the data-anchor-target I think, or it's not doing what I want

I have a bunch of scenes that all have the same background, my `pano` element.

```
<div id="pano"
     data--0p-top="top:0%; opacity:1; transform: scale(1);"
     data--200p-top="top:13%; opacity:0.5; transform: scale(2);"
     data--620p-top="top: 20%; transform: scale(3);"
     data--1000p-top="top:-100%; opacity:0.2; scale(4);">
</div>

<div id="scene1"
     data-anchor-target="#pano"
     data--50p-top="opacity:0.3; top: 20%; left: 5%; transform: scale(0);"
     data--100p-top="opacity:1; transform: scale(1); top: 10%; left:30%;"
     data--150p-top="opacity:0; transform: scale(1.5); top: -10%; left:60%;">
    <div class="cloud1"></div>
</div>

<div id="scene2" class="scene-text"
     data-anchor-target="#scene1"
     data--130p-top="transform: scale(0); opacity: 0.5; top: 27%;"
     data--150p-top="transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; top: 27%;"
     data--200p-top="transform: scale(1.2);"
     data--230p-top="transform: scale(3); opacity: 0;">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>This is a excerpt telling a story.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To my understanding `scene2`'s data tags should depend from `scene1`? but now they still seem dependent on `pano` as in the top?

---

My other issue is when I try to implement `skrollr menu` on this setup to alloq anchors to each scene it barely scrolls anywhere even if I place an element at the end and make an anchor to it. I also tried setting `data-menu-top` to the scene I wanted the link to go to.

My link test:
`<a href="#scene2" data-menu-top="700">Passenger Portal</a>` which only scrolls to the top of the page with a little offset. Changing the value of data-menu-top does nothing.

This is my initiation (and I do have jquery included ofc)

```
<script>
    var s = skrollr.init({
        smoothScrolling: true
        /*render: function (data) {
            //Log the current scroll position.
            console.log(data.curTop);
        }*/
    });

    skrollr.menu.init(s, {
        animate: true,

        //The easing function to use.
        easing: 'sqrt',

        //Multiply your data-[offset] values so they match those set in skrollr.init
        scale: 2,

        //How long the animation should take in ms.
        duration: function (currentTop, targetTop) {
            //By default, the duration is hardcoded at 500ms.
            return 500;

            //But you could calculate a value based on the current scroll position (`currentTop`) and the target scroll position (`targetTop`).
            //return Math.abs(currentTop - targetTop) * 10;
        },

        //If you pass a handleLink function you'll disable `data-menu-top` and `data-menu-offset`.
        //You are in control where skrollr will scroll to. You get the clicked link as a parameter and are expected to return a number.
        handleLink: function (link) {
            return 400;//Hardcoding 400 doesn't make much sense.
        },

        //By default skrollr-menu will only react to links whose href attribute contains a hash and nothing more, e.g. `href="#foo"`.
        //If you enable `complexLinks`, skrollr-menu also reacts to absolute and relative URLs which have a hash part.
        //The following will all work (if the user is on the correct page):
        //http://example.com/currentPage/#foo
        //http://example.com/currentDir/currentPage.html?foo=bar#foo
        ///?foo=bar#foo
        complexLinks: false,

        //This event is triggered right before we jump/animate to a new hash.
        change: function (newHash, newTopPosition) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with skrollr-menu only going down part way. Removing this line from the initiation script allowed it to scroll all the way to whatever anchor link I wanted:

```js
        handleLink: function (link) {
            return 400;//Hardcoding 400 doesn't make much sense.
        },
```

Comment: Intresting! I would have liked to try it, but I actually scrapped everything and started from scratch with scrollMagic. And to anyone reading this and is trying to do an "advanced" animation (more than one thing happeneing at the same time) I would highly recommend scrollMagic. If you even know a little javascript it will be 100x more customizable and dynamic!